# Does a (duplicated) file descriptor gets destroyed(closed) after going out of scope?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin, file-descriptor

I have the following code:

```
  pid_t child = fork();

  if(child == 0){

    close(fd[WRITE]);

    dup2(fd[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[READ]);

    if(/*condition*/){

      int file = open(argv[4], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0640);
      
      dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO);

    }
  
    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
  }
```

Does file get closed(destroyed) after it goes out of scope, in this case when it leaves the if-condition? Or it only gets closed when you call `close` and scopes don't really apply to file descriptors like they do to normal variables?
What I want to do in this code is output the input i get either to a file(if condition is true) or just put it to the `stdout`

Comment: C doesn't have destructors. You have to manually close the file.

Comment: No, it does not get closed. You lose the handle and so it cannot be closed (until program exit closes it automatically).

Comment: When a variable gets out of scope in C, it just gets out of scope, nothing else happens.

Comment: Not related, but you need to add a call to `_exit()` immediately after your call to `execlp()`.  If `execlp()` fails, your current code will continue running a copy of the parent process otherwise.  And note it's `_exit()` and not `exit()` - `exit()` will call the exit handlers for the *parent* process - including flushing buffers copied from the parent's address space.